# Profiling OpenCL kernels

Tags: profiling, opencl

I am trying to optimize my OpenCL kernels and all I have right now is NVidia Visual Profiler, which seems rather constrained. I would like to see line-by-line profile of kernels to better understand issues with coalescing, etc. Is there a way to get more thorough profiling data than the one, provided by Visual Profiler?

Answer (score 6):

I think that AMD CodeXL is what you are looking for. It's a free set of tools that contains an OpenCL debugger and a GPU profiler. 
The OpenCL debugger allows you to do line-by-line debugging of your OpenCL kernels and host code, view all variables across different workgroups, view special events and errors that occur, etc..
The GPU profiler has a nice feature that generates a timeline displaying how long your program spends on tasks like data transfer and kernel execution.

For more info and download links, check out http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/

Comment: OpenXL - GPUOPEN works only for AMD processors, which is a major limitation for many users

Comment: I think that you are mixing two different terms: CodeXL is a tool suite by AMD, and is one of the products that were open-sourced as part of AMD's GPUOpen initiative. I think that the whole purpose of this initiative was to allow developers and other players in the industry to extend these tools, so that they will support additional platforms.

Comment: Officially, CodeXL requires an AMD GPU, driver and SDK to profile OpenCL applications.
Please see the section Prerequisities in https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/CodeXL/releases/download/v2.0/CodeXL_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such tool but you can profile your code changes. Try measuring the speed of your code, change something and then measure it once again. clEnqueueNDRangeKernel has an Event argument which can be used with clGetEventProfilingInfo afterwards, the timer is very sharp, the accuracy is measured in order of microseconds. This is the only way to measure performance of a separate code part...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't test it but I just found this program http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBuggerCL.php. 
The description is: " This new product brings gDEBugger's advanced Debugging, Profiling and Memory Analysis abilities to the OpenCL developer's world..."

Answer (score 1):

[LTPV is an open-source, OpenCL profiler](https://github.com/LTPV/LTPV) that may fit your requirements. It is, for now, only working under Linux.

(disclosure: I am the developer of this tool)